# How to get usbmount to mount to a specific folder

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, media-server

I use Ubuntu server to run my Plex server. I’m wondering how I can get usbmount to mount my external hard drive to a specific folder. I have two partitions /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2. I need sdb2 to mount to /media/usb0 without changing after reboot. Right now it’s random every time I reboot. Sometimes sdb1 will mount to usb0